# Autocorrelation of a $L$-point moving average system

Tags: discrete-signals, autocorrelation

The $L$-point moving system is:

$$y[n]=\frac 1L\sum_{k=0}^{L-1}x[n-k]$$

$x[n]$ is a Bernoulli random signal with $\beta=0.5$ (equal probability)

The autocorrelation of $x[n]$: $\psi_{xx}[m]=\delta[m]$

Normally for this type of problems, I would start with $h[n]$, then use the property

$$\Psi_{yy}[m]=|H(e^{j\omega})|^2\Psi_{xx}(e^{j\omega}).$$

However, since I only have the difference equation, I can't seem to find $h[n]$.

I'm trying to compute directly using the equation $\psi_{yy}[m]=E(y[n]y^*[n+m])$, then represent $y[n]$ in terms of $x[n]$, but this seems to be a dead end as well.

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Hint: from the equation for $y[n]$ it's quite straightforward to figure out the corresponding $h[n]$.

Comment: Further hint: since $y[n]=T\{x[n]\}$ and $h[n]=T\{\delta[n]\}$ , let $x[n]=\delta[n]$ so that $y[n]=h[n]$

Comment: I tried plugging in $\delta[n]$ as the input and got (1/L)$\sum_{k=0}^{L-1}\delta[n-k]$, but this is not a closed-form expression which is needed to find the autocorrelation of y. How can I go from here to get a closed-form expression of the frequency response?

Comment: You said normally you would start with h[n] and proceed? Now you have h[n] you can proceed. That's a closed form FIR filter. You can now find $H(e^{j\omega})$ as DTFT of h[n]. Cannot you take the DTFT of h[n] ?

Comment: I did. $H(e^{j\omega)}=\frac 1L (\frac {1-e^{j\omega L}}{1-e^{j\omega}})$, but then $|H(e^{j\omega})|^2$ was very complicated and depended on $\omega$. Therefore $\Psi_{yy} = |H(e^{j\omega})|^2$, but I don't know how to take the inverse DFTF to get the answer.

Comment: So you can find $\Psi_{yy}=|H(e^{j\omega})|^2$ but yo cannot invert it back to find $\psi_{yy}[m]$... Why not using well known convolution theorem i.e. $DTFT\{x[n]*y[n]\} = X(\omega)Y(\omega)$ with $|H(\omega)|^2=H(\omega)H(\omega)^*$

Comment: $\Psi_{yy}=|H(e^{j\omega})|^2=\frac 1L (\frac {2-e^{j\omega L}}{2-e^{j\omega}})$, but I am not sure how to find the Inverse DFTF of this function...

Comment: As I said, from convolution theorem, if $\Psi_{yy}(w)=DTFT\{\psi_{yy}[m]\}=|H(w)|^2=H(w)H(w)^*$ then $\psi_{yy}[m]=IDFT\{H(w)\} * IDFT\{H(w)^*\} = h[m]*h[-m]^*$

Comment: Yes, however $H(e^{j\omega})=\frac 1L (\frac {1-e^{j\omega L}}{1-e^{j\omega}})$ does not converge at infinity. How am I supposed to take the $IDFT$?

Comment: First, H(w) does converge as it already exists. Second, I repeat here: ACF of output y[n] is : $\psi_{yy}[m] = h[m]*h[-m]^*$. Assuming input x[n] was WSS with ACF of $\delta[m]$

Comment: Take qwt185's $H(e^{j\omega)}=\frac 1L (\frac {1-e^{j\omega L}}{1-e^{j\omega}})$ extract the exponentials for half value; now you have a exponential times the ratio of two sine fucntions.  When you calculate the power the exponential factor disappears and you are left with sin(w*L/2)/sin(w) to conjugate  and multiply.